# Equation of Motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have an equation of motion with an additional viscous force shown below:
$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = x^3 - x^5 - \frac{dx}{dt} $

And the question is `Rewrite as a system for x(t) and v(t)`. I don't even understand how to begin this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\dot{x}=v$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=\ddot{x}=\dot{v}$. The original equation can now be written as $\dot{v}=x^3-x^5-v$. In consequence, the second order differential equation has been replaced by a system of two first order differential equations, namely

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l l}
  \dot{x}=v\\
  \dot{v}=x^3-x^5-v
\end{array}\right.$$

Note that the derivatives depend only on $x$ and $v$.

Comment: okay I'm with you so far in terms of converting the equation to a first order. But I still don't understand what to do from there....wait...do i solve it like a linear equation $\dot{v} + v = x^3-x^5$

Comment: This system of equations is non-linear, so it will be difficult to solve it analytically. However, there are plenty of numerical methods for systems of first order differential equations. If you have initial conditions for $x$ and $v$, then you can easily compute the derivatives at that time, which can then be used to find $x$ and $v$ at another time; see [Euler method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method).

Answer (score 3):

$$\dot{x}=v$$

$$\dot{v}=x^3-x^5-v$$

Comment: sorry, I'm really stupid and I'm not seeing much. I actually wrote my equation like $a = x^3 - x^5 - v$, kinda the same ...but then what do I do from here

Comment: $a$ is the time derivative of $v$, that's the point.  Now you have two first-degree equations rather than a single, second-degree equation.

Comment: so like I said below, I just solve it like a linear equation?

Comment: @Richard: not really - the equations are coupled together, and non-linear.  This is just another way of expressing them, it doesn't really simplify things much except in that it keeps the unknowns to first-order derivatives.